# Simple Type Joda Date Time with Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, jackson, retrofit2, jodatime

I have a model with a field:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = DateTimeDeserializer.class)
private DateTime expiryTimeFirebaseCustomAccessToken;
```

With env:

```
compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.9.4')
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.4.0')
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
```

And java code:

```
final JodaModule jodaModule = new JodaModule();
        jodaModule.addDeserializer(DateTime.class,
                DateTimeDeserializer.forType(DateTime.class));
        jodaModule.addDeserializer(ReadableDateTime.class,
                DateTimeDeserializer.forType(ReadableDateTime.class));
        jodaModule.addDeserializer(ReadableInstant.class,
                DateTimeDeserializer.forType(ReadableInstant.class));

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(jodaModule);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(serverAddress)                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(objectMapper))
                .build();
```

And json response:

```
"expiryTimeFirebaseCustomAccessToken": "2018-03-27T10:44:06.590Z"
```

But, I got this error:

> Failed to narrow type [simple type, class org.joda.time.DateTime] with
>   annotation (value
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.DateTimeDeserializer), from
>   'setExpiryTimeFirebaseCustomAccessToken': Class
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.DateTimeDeserializer not
>   subtype of [simple type, class org.joda.time.DateTime

Comment: My bad, I should use:

@JsonDeserialize(using = DateTimeDeserializer.class)
private DateTime expiryTimeFirebaseCustomAccessToken;

But, now I got error:

failure:Class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.DateTimeDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor

Answer (score 2):

And I found solution:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private DateTime expiryTimeFirebaseCustomAccessToken;
```

with class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.cfg.FormatConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.cfg.JacksonJodaDateFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.DateTimeDeserializer;

    import org.joda.time.DateTime;

    /**
     * Created by rudi on 3/28/18.
     */

    public class MyDateTimeDeserializer extends DateTimeDeserializer {

        public MyDateTimeDeserializer() {
            super(DateTime.class, FormatConfig.DEFAULT_DATETIME_PARSER);
        }

        public MyDateTimeDeserializer(Class<?> cls, JacksonJodaDateFormat format) {
            super(cls, format);
        }

    }
```